# How to create Prepend extension method for IQueryable<T> which is compatible with Linq to Entities 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

For a project using LINQ to Entities 4.0, I have a setting in which I need to return a query with a (constant) value prepended.  If I were coding it in SQL it would look something like this:

```
select 0 as ID, 'default' as Name
union
select ID, Name from X
```

For this project, I would like to create a generic extension method to IQueryable that accepts a constant value returns a query with the constant value prepended as its result.  The process should not trigger enumeration as I don't want the query to trigger a database hit unless the other code in the application actually enumerates against the query.

Ideally, I would like the IQueryable result to be joinable to other Linq to Entities queries and processable by the L2E provider.

I have tried a couple of varations, but realized they were going to trigger enumeration instead of adding to the query.  My latest attempt extends the query without enumerating (as desired), but returns an error:

```
    public static IQueryable<T> Prepend<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query
        , T value
        )
    {
        return query
            .Where(t => false).DefaultIfEmpty(value)
            .Concat(query);
    }
```

The error is, "Unable to create a constant value of type 'OCEAN.Business.Pocos.ExclusionIncomeType'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.".

I've tried searching for similar concepts, including appending a value, but to no avail.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using an actual `Union`?  `query.Union(new[] {value})`?  I know Linq-to-SQL doesn't like that, but maybe Linq-to-Entities can handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final answer:

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> PrependEnumerator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T value)  
    { 
        yield return value; 
        foreach (var item in sequence) 
        { 
            yield return item; 
        } 
    } 

    public static IQueryable<T> Prepend<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query
        , T value
        )
    {
        return query.PrependEnumerator(value).AsQueryable();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) to create a new `IEnumerable<T>` instance that returns your default value first:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Prepend<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T value) 
{
    yield return value;
    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

This will create an enumerator that will first return your default item, and then enumerate through the query.

Comment: Sounds promising.  Ideally, I would like the IQueryable result to be joinable to other Linq to Entities queries and processable by the L2E provider.  However, this would still solve my basic need.

Comment: On reflection, this is technically not a match since IEnumerable<T> does not implement IQueryable<T> (though the opposite is true). However, I _might_ be able to get this to work for my problem.

Comment: // that got me partway.  final solution:  
        private static IEnumerable<T> PrependEnumerator<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T value)  
        { 
            yield return value; 
            foreach (var item in sequence) 
            { 
                yield return item; 
            } 
        } 

        public static IQueryable<T> Prepend<T>(
            this IQueryable<T> query
            , T value
            )
        {
            return query.PrependEnumerator(value).AsQueryable();
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
private static IEnumerable<T> PrependEnumerator<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence, 
    T value
    ) 
{ 
    yield return value; 
    foreach (var item in sequence) { yield return item; } 
} 
public static IQueryable<T> Prepend<T>( 
    this IQueryable<T> query , 
    T value 
    ) 
{ 
    return query.PrependEnumerator(value).AsQueryable(); 
}
```